# PHP - Hide Previously Selected Category from Category 2 Option List

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, filter, categories

It's pretty simple.

When a user is filling out a form, they can place the listing in two categories. Once the user selects their first category from a drop down menu. How can I make that category not be an option in the second drop down menu.

The issue is, the user can pick the same category twice. Here is what I have as a base:

```
            <li>
              <select name="category_1" tabindex="5">
                <option value="">Choose a category...</option>
                {foreach from=$cats item='cat'}
                  {if $cat.active}
                    <option value="{$cat.id}"{if $cat.id == $smarty.session.formVars.category_1} selected="selected"{/if}>{$cat.name} ({$cat.description})</option>
                  {/if}
                {/foreach}
              </select>
            </li>

            {if $smarty.session.formVars.category_2}
            <li>
              <select name="category_2">
                <option>Choose a category...</option>
                {foreach from=$cats item='cat'}
                  {if $cat.active}
                    <option value="{$cat.id}"{if $cat.id == $smarty.session.formVars.category_2} selected="selected"{/if}>{$cat.name} ({$cat.description})</option>
                  {/if}
                {/foreach}
              </select>
              <a href='#' class="category_delete">x</a>
            </li>
            {/if}
```

Here is the current JS to go with it:

```
// Build category options
var cat_master = "";
$("#cat_master li").each(function(index, element) {
  cat_master += "<option value='" + $(element).find(".cat_id").text() + "'>" + $(element).find(".cat_name").text() + "</option>";
});

$(".category_add").click(function(e) {

  var cat_count = $("#categories > li").size();

  if (cat_count < AuthJ.Post.category_limit) {

    var next_cat = cat_count + 1;
    var new_select = "<select name='category_" + next_cat + "'><option value=''>Choose a category ...</option>" + cat_master + "</select>";

    $("#categories").append("<li>" + new_select + "</li>");

    // TODO: Remove previously selected categories from the new options list

    if (cat_count == (AuthJ.Post.category_limit - 1)) {
      $(this).hide(); // Hide the add new category link if we're at the category limit
    }

    $('<a href="#" class="category_delete">x</a>')
      .click(function(e){ deleteCategory(e, this); })
      .show()
      .appendTo('#categories > li:last');
  }

  e.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: where is the jQuery code corresponding to this ?

Comment: Edited initial question to include.

Comment: did you look at the solution posted below? Are you making use of MySQL/database in your application ?

Answer (score 0):

Inside on change event of drop down 1, get the value of drop down 1 in value_in_first_drop_down and use the following syntax to remove from second frop down

$("#drop_down_2_id option[value=value_in_first_drop_down]").remove();

You will still need to handle the case when user changes his option choice from first drop down. As the element removed first has to be added back and then the newly chosen element is to be removed from second drop down